# How to prevent the previous deleted data to be restored by the database set in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After each writing data progress in Apache IoTDB, I will delete the data of the device saved in the previous progress, and then start to insert the data of the current progress. Occasionally there will be a problem of data deleted in previous progress being restored. I checked the database operation record, and verified that the database has restored the data deleted two hours ago. I wonder if this kind of insertion process is not allowed, or what can I do to prevent the data restore happening again?